# Create CMSampleBufferRef from an AudioInputIOProc

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, audio, core-audio

I have an `AudioInputIOProc` that I'm getting an `AudioBufferList` from. I need to convert this `AudioBufferList` to a `CMSampleBufferRef`.

Here's the code I've written so far:

```
- (void)handleAudioSamples:(const AudioBufferList*)samples numSamples:(UInt32)numSamples hostTime:(UInt64)hostTime {
// Create a CMSampleBufferRef from the list of samples, which we'll own

  AudioStreamBasicDescription monoStreamFormat;
  memset(&monoStreamFormat, 0, sizeof(monoStreamFormat));
  monoStreamFormat.mSampleRate = 44100;
  monoStreamFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC;
  monoStreamFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved;
  monoStreamFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 4;
  monoStreamFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
  monoStreamFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 4;
  monoStreamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
  monoStreamFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;

  CMFormatDescriptionRef format = NULL;
  OSStatus status = CMAudioFormatDescriptionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, &monoStreamFormat, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, &format);
  if (status != noErr) {
    // really shouldn't happen
    return;
  }

  mach_timebase_info_data_t tinfo;
  mach_timebase_info(&tinfo);

  UInt64 _hostTimeToNSFactor = (double)tinfo.numer / tinfo.denom;

  uint64_t timeNS = (uint64_t)(hostTime * _hostTimeToNSFactor);
  CMTime presentationTime = CMTimeMake(timeNS, 1000000000);
  CMSampleTimingInfo timing = { CMTimeMake(1, 44100), kCMTimeZero, kCMTimeInvalid };

  CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = NULL;
  status = CMSampleBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, false, NULL, NULL, format, numSamples, 1, &timing, 0, NULL, &sampleBuffer);
  if (status != noErr) {
    // couldn't create the sample buffer
    NSLog(@"Failed to create sample buffer");
    CFRelease(format);
    return;
  }

  // add the samples to the buffer
  status = CMSampleBufferSetDataBufferFromAudioBufferList(sampleBuffer,
                                                        kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                        kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                        0,
                                                        samples);
  if (status != noErr) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to add samples to sample buffer");
    CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
    CFRelease(format);
    NSLog(@"Error status code: %d", status);
    return;
  }

  [self addAudioFrame:sampleBuffer];

  NSLog(@"Original sample buf size: %ld for %d samples from %d buffers, first buffer has size %d", CMSampleBufferGetTotalSampleSize(sampleBuffer), numSamples, samples->mNumberBuffers, samples->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize);
  NSLog(@"Original sample buf has %ld samples", CMSampleBufferGetNumSamples(sampleBuffer));
}
```

Now, I'm unsure how to calculate the numSamples given this function definition of an AudioInputIOProc:

```
OSStatus AudioTee::InputIOProc(AudioDeviceID inDevice, const AudioTimeStamp *inNow, const AudioBufferList *inInputData, const AudioTimeStamp *inInputTime, AudioBufferList *outOutputData, const AudioTimeStamp *inOutputTime, void *inClientData)
```

This definition exists in the [AudioTee.cpp](https://github.com/pje/WavTap/blob/master/App/AudioTee.cpp) file in WavTap.

The error I'm getting is a `CMSampleBufferError_RequiredParameterMissing` error with the error code `-12731` when I try to call `CMSampleBufferSetDataBufferFromAudioBufferList`.

Update:

To clarify on the problem a bit, the following is the format of the audio data I'm getting from the AudioDeviceIOProc:

`Channels: 2, Sample Rate: 44100, Precision: 32-bit, Sample Encoding: 32-bit Signed Integer PCM, Endian Type: little, Reverse Nibbles: no, Reverse Bits: no`

I'm getting an `AudioBufferList`* that has all the audio data (30 seconds of video) that I need to convert to a `CMSampleBufferRef`* and add those sample buffers to a video (that is 30 seconds long) that is being written to disk via an `AVAssetWriterInput`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three things look wrong:

1. You declare that the format ID is `kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC`, but configure it as LPCM. So try

   `monoStreamFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;`

   You also call the format "mono" when it's configured as stereo.
2. Why use `mach_timebase_info` which could leave gaps in your audio presentation timestamps? Use sample count instead:

   `CMTime presentationTime = CMTimeMake(numSamplesProcessed, 44100);`
3. Your `CMSampleTimingInfo` looks wrong, and you're not using `presentationTime`. You set the buffer's duration as 1 sample long when it can be `numSamples` and its presentation time to zero which can't be right. Something like this would make more sense:

   `CMSampleTimingInfo timing = { CMTimeMake(numSamples, 44100), presentationTime, kCMTimeInvalid };`

And some questions:

Does your `AudioBufferList` have the expected 2 `AudioBuffers`? 
Do you have a runnable version of this?

p.s. I'm guilty of it myself, but allocating memory on the audio thread is [considered harmful](http://atastypixel.com/blog/four-common-mistakes-in-audio-development/) in audio dev.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. The input format is as follows:

`
Channels       : 2
Sample Rate    : 44100
Precision      : 32-bit
Sample Encoding: 32-bit Signed Integer PCM
Endian Type    : little
Reverse Nibbles: no
Reverse Bits   : no
`

I need to add this to a MP4 video.

I have an AudioBufferList that contains all of the audio I want to add to the video. 

Thanks for the response, I'll try to setup a runnable project for this.

Comment: @AtharvaVaidya can you add that to the question and say what you pass it to?

Comment: That looks like a 4th problem then: your input samples are 32 bit but your sample buffer is 16bit.